# Basis of a topology

Tags: general-topology

Does every topology have a unique basis? What I mean is if there is more than one topology that can be obtained from a given basis, which topology should I consider when they say the topology generated by the given basis?

Comment: A topology has many bases. But a basis generates a unique topology.

Comment: Can you specify this topology?

Comment: In $\Bbb R$, for example, you can use open balls as a basis, or sets which only contain interior points, and you generate the same topology.

Comment: @RithwikVidyarthi the topology is that a set is open if it is a union of some elements in the basis. This "some" could be zero, finite, or infinite.

Comment: So there isn't a unique topology corresponding to a given basis.

Comment: @RithwikVidyarthi there isn't a unique basis corresponding to a given topological space. But given a basis, there is only one topological space.

Answer (score 2):

No, there can be many basis for the same topology (but a basis generates a unique topology).

For example in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for $r>0$, let 
$$B((x_0,y_0),r):=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2<r^2\}$$
and
$$S((x_0,y_0),r):=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|<r\}.$$
Then $\{B((x_0,y_0),r): (x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2, r>0\}$ and $\{S((x_0,y_0),r): (x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2, r>0\}$ are two different basis (actually they have no set in common) for the euclidean topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

P.S. One more example. The topology $\big\{\emptyset,\{x\},\{y\},\{x,y\}\big\}$ for the finite set $\{x,y\}$ has the following bases:

1. $\big\{\{x\},\{y\}\big\}$
2. $\big\{\emptyset,\{x\},\{y\}\big\}$
3. $\big\{\{x\},\{y\},\{x,y\}\big\}$
4. $\big\{\emptyset,\{x\},\{y\},\{x,y\}\big\}$

Comment: Okay. But can a basis generate more than one topology?

Comment: @Rithwik Vidyarthi No, a basis generates a unique topology.

Comment: What if I take one basis element along with the empty set and the whole set? Isn't this a topology generated by the basis?

Comment: @Rithwik Vidyarthi What do you mean? Note that a base should cover the whole space $X$ that is the union of all elements yields $X$.

Comment: I'll give an example. Let $X = \{a,b,c\}$ and $\mathcal{B} = \{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$. Then isn't $\tau = \{X, \emptyset, \{a\}\}$ a topology?

Comment: @Rithwik Vidyarthi Yes, $\tau$ is a topology for $X$ but $\tau$ is not generated by $\mathcal{B}$. $\mathcal{B}$ gives another topology on $X$ (different from $\tau$).

Comment: Ah...I got it..@Bernard8 has clarified it.Is  $\mathcal{B}$ here still a basis for $\tau$ though?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a set.

For any family of subsets $\mathcal A$ of $X$ there is another family of subsets $\mathcal B$ where $B \in \mathcal B$ iff it is equal to the union of elements in $A$. Let $f$ be a function which takes any collection of subsets of $X$ and returns the collection of all unions of those subsets as an output.

If you apply $f$ to a basis $\mathcal A$ you will get back a topology of $X$. It is in this sense that we say a basis generates exactly one topology and we call $\mathcal A$ a basis for $f(\mathcal A)$

Conversely, if you already have a topology $\tau$ on the space, then you may be able to find a basis $\mathcal A$ such that $f(\mathcal A) = \tau$. This basis will almost never be unique as a topology is its own basis.

Comment: Thanks.I think thats where I was off.

Comment: I think the confusing part is that when you want a basis for a particular topology, there are many possible choices. Conversely, when you have a collection of sets which form a basis, there is only one topology that it generates.